@ Symbol as parameter Name in Hibernate 6.6.1.Final
I updated to 6.6.1 from 6.4.4 and wonder why
entityManager().createNamedQuery(MyClass.MY_QUERY, SomeOther.class).setParameter("@customerId", customerId).getResultList();
doesn't work any more.
MY_QUERY is a @NamedNativeQuery
It seems the @ in the parameter is the problem. When I remove it in the parameter and in my query string, i.e. :customerId instead of :@customerId it works again.
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.UnknownParameterException: No parameter named ':@customerId' in query with named parameters []
    at org.hibernate@6.6.1.Final//org.hibernate.query.internal.ParameterMetadataImpl.getQueryParameter(ParameterMetadataImpl.java:269)
    at org.hibernate@6.6.1.Final//org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.getBinding(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:170)
    at org.hibernate@6.6.1.Final//org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractCommonQueryContract.setParameter(AbstractCommonQueryContract.java:817)
    at org.hibernate@6.6.1.Final//org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.setParameter(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:595)
    at org.hibernate@6.6.1.Final//org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractQuery.setParameter(AbstractQuery.java:405)
    at org.hibernate@6.6.1.Final//org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeQueryImpl.setParameter(NativeQueryImpl.java:1313)
    at org.hibernate@6.6.1.Final//org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeQueryImpl.setParameter(NativeQueryImpl.java:120)



Found it. The reason is this commit and issue HHH-17759
The new check Character.isJavaIdentifierStart( sqlString.charAt( indx + 1 )
results in false, e.g. for the "special" @ character. Because of this a named parameter is not extracted any longer at all.
I wonder why the @ - which is ubiquious in sql server for parameters - is not allowed here any more.
To work around this I need to replace the @ containing parameters throughout my code. Thanks :-(
To be fair. It was never compliant to the JPA spec. E.g. JPA 2.1 says:

4.6.4.2 Named Parameters
A named parameter is denoted by an identifier that is prefixed by the ":" symbol. It follows the rules for
identifiers defined in Section 4.4.1. Named parameters are case
sensitive.

and moreover

4.4.1 Identifiers
An identifier is a character sequence of unlimited length. The character sequence must begin with a Java identifier start
character, and all other characters must be Java identifier part
characters. An identifier start character is any character for which
the method Character.isJavaIdentifierStart returns true. This includes
the underscore (_) character and the dollar sign ($) character. An
identifier part character is any character for which the method
Character.isJavaIdentifierPart returns true. The question mark (?)
character is reserved for use by the Java Persistence query language.

